# block length - Rijndael algorithm

Tags: c++, encryption

Well, I downloaded Rijndael sources from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr

I have the following code:

```
int AutoUpdater::GetVersion()
{
std::ifstream file("ver.dat", std::ios::out );
if(file.fail())
    return 0;
file.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
int len = (int)file.tellg();
file.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

char* line = new char[len];

file.read(line,len);
file.close();

CRijndael crypt;
crypt.MakeKey("MIUJkHyHnjHyGtqO", "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16, 16);

char * decrypted = new char[len];
crypt.Decrypt(line,decrypted,len);


delete[] line;
delete [] decrypted;

return atoi(line);
}
```

But it is giving this error: "Data not multiple of Block Size"

My file to encrypt has to have a fixed length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad it with trailing zeros to fill out the block size.  You could also consider prefixing the byte length, to recover the original exact length.

Answer (score 1):

Rijndael is a block cipher.  Your input doesn't need fixed length, but it does need to be a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for Rijndael).  There are lots of [padding methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) you can use to ensure that.  I like PKCS7, nice and simple.

What I'm confused by is why your input file is not a multiple of the block size.  You couldn't have properly encrypted data using Rijndael that gave you such a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Rijndael is a block cipher.  You should encode your data with a length field in front.  The bits beyond the length field can be safely ignored by the decoder.